# I have a List of lists containing 4170 elements and I want to divide them to 139 lists each containing 30 different elements?

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

```
 are_different(List1,List2):-
    nth0(0,List1,Slot1),
    nth0(0,List2,Slot2),
    Slot1\==Slot2.


fillSchedule([30,_,_,_,_,_,__],S).

fillSchedule([H|T],[H1|T1]):-
    are_different(H,H1),
    H1 = H,
    fillSchedule(T,T1).

fillSchedule([H|T],L):-
    fillSchedule(T,L).
```

the lists inside the big 4170 element list are in the following form

```
[1,A,B,C,D,E,F],[1,A1,B1,C1,D1,F1].......[5,_,_,_,_,_,_].....[30,_,..]
```

Each list is different from the other list in some way or another but not neccasrily the first element (1),(2) etc which is the most important factor .I want as one possible solution of the fill Schedule predicate a list consisting of 30 elements extracted from the first big list like this `[[1,...],[2,...],[3,...] etc till 30`,  the next solution for the predicate should contain another list of lists containing 30 elements but each one different from the first 30 chosen and so on till we have no more elements to choose from the original 4170 elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make a predicate that will filter out only those lists that begin with a specified number
2. Use that predicate to make 30 lists, each of whose members all start with the same element (1..30)
3. fillSchedule can then create its solutions by drawing from each of those 30 lists: the base case would take all heads, the recursive would be given all 30 tails to process.  fillSchedule would fail once on of the 30 sub-lists gets used up.

Comment: little question in step 2 should I use findall to get the 30 lists ? then use the resulting list in step 3 ?

Comment: You could use findall to implement the predicate described in step 1, call it 30 times to make your 30 lists, and then pass them to fillSchedule.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach:

```
fillSchedule(InL, OutL):-
    numlist(1, 30, Heads),
    fillSchedule(Heads, Heads, InL, [], OutL).

fillSchedule([], _, _, OutL, OutL).
fillSchedule([], Heads, InL, _, OutL):-
  fillSchedule(Heads, Heads, InL, [], OutL).
fillSchedule([Item|TailHeads], Heads, InL, MedL, OutL):-
  select([Item|Rest], InL, NInL),
  % !, This cut would prevent combinations
  fillSchedule(TailHeads, Heads, NInL, [[Item|Rest]|MedL], OutL).
```

It builds a list with the heads and then selects items from the input list which have each item from the heads. The commented cut prevents combinations if you uncomment it.